# Javascript game buggy on IOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, game-physics

I am making a platformer entirely with the HTML5 canvas without using any libraries. here is a link:
https://www.blanccanvascollective.com/game

It has basic physics, collision detection, etc. All the calculations are done using boxes and boundaries without any rotation. It runs perfectly fine on my PC browsers. I've tested it on chrome, edge and IE.

When I test it on my sisters apple it is incredibly buggy. Even in Chrome. The wix site doesn't even load on safari. The character bobs up and down constantly and when he jumps he flies across the screen.

I thought at first this was due to my timing calculations, so I have made sure to use performance.now(); instead of Date.now(); using this function:

```
window.performance = window.performance || {};
 performance.now = (function() {
    return performance.now       ||
        performance.mozNow    ||
        performance.msNow     ||
        performance.oNow      ||
        performance.webkitNow ||            
        Date.now;  /*none found - fallback to browser default */
})();
```

But that did not help at all.

I was just wondering what could possibly be the cause of this? There are no exotic functions in my code that wouldn't be understood by a MAC. My code is very simple, just a bunch of if statements and increments.

Sorry the question is so vague, I just have no idea what could be the cause of it. If you have a MAC, I'd appreciate it if you tested my game and gave feedback.

Comment: I tried playing your game with firefox on win7, the physics were a bit buggy but I think your game has some nice polish.

Comment: Thank you very much. In what way was it buggy?

Comment: It was in the movement and collision detection. To me it looks as though it was due to incorrect delta time values.